# Idiomatic way in TypeScript to parse JSON?

Tags: json, typescript

I have an interface `IMsg` and want to parse JSON so that I have an object that implements my `IMsg` interface.

This code

```js
interface IMsg {
  text: string;
  channels: Set<string>;
}
const msg: IMsg = JSON.parse(`{
  "text": "test",
  "channels": ["latest", "something"]
}`);
console.log(msg.channels.has('latest'));
```

will produce this error at runtime:

```
TypeError: msg.channels.has is not a function
```

since `msg.channels` is not a `Set<string>`.

1. Why does the compiler not complain that I try to assign an object of `any` to `msg`, which is of type `IMsg`?
2. What would be the most idiomatic, concise way to correctly parse my JSON into `msg` without much boilerplate code?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the compiler not complain that I try to assign an object of any to msg, which is of type IMsg?

Because [the type `any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) precisely means: don't make any type verification on this variable. It can be anything, just as in JavaScript.

> What would be the most idiomatic, concise way to correctly parse my JSON into msg without much boilerplate code?

I would use something like

```
interface JsonMessage {
  text: string;
  channels: Array<string>;
}

const jsonMessage: JsonMessage = JSON.parse(`{
  "text": "test",
  "channels": ["latest", "something"]
}`);

const message: IMsg = {
  text: jsonMessage.text,
  channels: new Set(jsonMessage.channels)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to JB Nizet's response, I created a separate interface for JSON messages. However, I did not want to repeat every single field.

The following code takes `IMsg` as a base interface. It removes the `channels: Set<string>` field and adds it back with the type `string[]`. To convert between the two I wrote a converter function `parseMsg`.

```js
interface IMsg {
  text: string;
  channels: Set<string>;
}

// create new interface for JSON handling based on IMsg
// and replace "channels: Set<string>" with "channels: string[]" 
type IMsgJSON = Omit<IMsg, 'channels'> & {
  channels: string[],
};

// convert from IMsgJSON to IMsg
function parseMsg(msgJSON: IMsgJSON): IMsg {
  const { channels, ...otherFields } = msgJSON;
  return {
    channels: new Set<string>(channels),
    ...otherFields,
  };
}

let msg = parseMsg(JSON.parse(`{
  "text": "test",
  "channels": ["latest", "something"]
}`));
console.log(msg.channel.has('latest'));
```